# External Trigger Options / Kubernetes to start/stop spring integration poller

Tags: spring-integration

I have a `poller` that runs every x seconds. I would like to control the `start/stop` of the `poller` and also be able to run it only once. An external call should be able to control this.

1. Start poller and continue polling every x intervals
2. Stop the poller
3. Poll only once and stop -> How to do this?

The polling is done using an `inbound-channel-adapter` with a `poller`. I am polling in configuration data of external systems to which the downstream flows connect to get data and route them to other systems

I can either use poller lifecycle methods or a control bus within the same context to configure the above calls.

How can I trigger this logic? The poller will run on kubernetes. Some options are:

1. HTTP
2. Actuator
3. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the Spring Boot Actuator is based on HTTP endpoints anyway. so, technically no difference from end-user perspective.

If you really can write some REST service with commands like you describer, then you indeed can inject a `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` into that service and delegate to its `start()` and `stop()`.

I think "poll only once" you can achieve with the boolean state variable which you can consult with from the `MessageSourceMutator.beforeReceive()` advice injected into that poller. This way you will leave a regular polling trigger untouched.

See also JMS support (if that is available from Kubernetes) : https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/system-management.html#jmx-mbean-exporter

Comment: Thank you for the solutions. I will try the approaches and post my implementation here. For the `poll only once`, I already have a `ReceiveMessageAdvice` to avoid overlapping polling sessions. Any other options in the framework, any suggestions?

Comment: You also can take a look into a `CompoundTrigger` so, whenever you need "only once", you call its `setOverride()` for some `OnlyOnceTrigger` implementation (you can find some in the framework). Otherwise you reset it into `null` to let the regular trigger to do the job.

Comment: `OnlyOnceTrigger` is in a test package`org.springframework.integration.test.util`. It seems a bit odd to include a test package class in core logic. May be it can be moved to a main packages in future?

Comment: Well, that one is indeed for testing purposes. I showed you it as a place to borrow ideas